# Easiest way to copy a mysql database from windows to linux?

Tags: mysql

I dont have perl install on windows. I would like to copy the entire testdb to testdb on my linux VM. What is the easiest way to do that? I can run code on my windows machine to connect to both DB and do sql operations. I am using C#.NET so if i need to write code and its simple then i'm open to that.

Comment: Very abbreviated: `mysqldump > dump.sql`; then `mysql < dump.sql`.

Comment: Extending on Pekka, if Windows happens to serve ssh... `ssh user@windowsBox mysqldump databaseName | mysql -uroot`

Comment: I thought mysqldump was a perl script. So its not... GREAT! I am semi familiar with it.

Comment: When using mysqldump on Windows, use `mysldump --result-file=dump.sql` instead of `mysqldump > dump.sql`! Otherwise all \n's become \r\n's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHPMyAdmin it has an export feature which makes it *very* easy to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL WorkBench 5.2.22 will allow you to do this very easily.